# Из GSAP в WEBGL

Tags: svg, typescript, webgl, gsap

Есть приложение в ангуляре, которое использует GSAP анимацию. Оно меняет svg с помощью timeline, а точнее, Есть один SVG и внутри него много `<g>` и они анимируются с помощью `display:none-block`. Можно ли с помощью WebGL сделать тоже самое?

Функция рисующая анимацию на данный момент

```
private drawAnimation() {
            this.timeline = new TimelineMax({
            onStart: this.onTweenStart.bind(this),
            onComplete: this.onTweenComplete.bind(this)
        });

    let item: any;
    const keys: any = Object.keys(this.queue);
    this.timeline.pause();
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        item = this.queue[keys[i]];
        this.timeline.fromTo('#' + item.name, item.duration, item.from, item.to, item.position);
    }

    this.animationAudio = this.audio;
    if (this.animationAudioSub && !this.animationAudioSub.closed) {
        this.animationAudioSub.unsubscribe();
    }
    this.animationAudioSub = this.animationAudio.play(this.assetsUrls[0])
        .subscribe(() => {
            if (this.animationAudioSub && !this.animationAudioSub.closed) {
                this.animationAudioSub.unsubscribe();
            }
            if (this.isComplete) {
                this.activityService
                    .sendMessageToModule
                    .next({name: MessageConstants.ANIMATION_COMPLETED});
            }
            this.isComplete = true;
        });
    this.timeline.play();
    if (!document.hasFocus()) {
        this.pauseAnimation();
    }
}
```

Comment: С помощью WebGL можно сделать все что угодно.

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий. Вы хотите узнать можно или нет, или узнать как это сделать? Если хотите узнать как, то в вашем вопросе не хватает исходных данных.

Comment: Вы бы оформили код в виде демки. Пока что это кусок кода, который что-то как-то делает.